# Why an instance constant has a value when the object has all fields set to default?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }
}

class A {
    A() {
        System.out.println("A constructor before");
        action();
        System.out.println("A constructor after");
    }

    protected void action() {
        System.out.println("Never called");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private final int finalField = 42;
    private int field = 99;

    B() {
        System.out.println("B constructor");
        action();
    }

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("B action, finalField=" + finalField + ", field=" + field);
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
A constructor before
B action, finalField=42, field=0
A constructor after
B constructor
B action, finalField=42, field=99
```

I confused by this line :

```
B action, finalField=42, field=0
```

Object B is not completely initialized and when we call method "action" from super class constructor - variable "field" has a default value, but the final variable "finalField" already has value 42.

When was the "finalField" initialized?

Comment: The link from Turing has the answer, but great question with clear formatting.

Comment: The dupe seems incorrect to me, it doesn't seem to explain the seemingly different initialization orders of `field` and `finalField`. (Looking at the byte code, both field and finalField are initialized in B's constructor after calling A's constructor, so something else is going on here). Voting to reopen

Comment: Thank you! I read the article by the link [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5], but I still have a question remains why final variable does not set to a default value (in this case 0).

Comment: Look at the bytecode and see what's different between the normal and the final field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a final field is initialized with a [*constant expression* (15.29)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29), it's called a [*constant variable* (4.12.4)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

```
private final int finalField = 42;
```

This means that the string

```
"B action, finalField=" + finalField + ", field="
```

is a *constant expression* itself and its value is determined at compile time. If you inspect the compiled class file you will in fact find the string `B action, finalField=42, field=` in the constant pool section.

In general, when a field that is a constant variable is used, it has to be replaced by its value at compile time. It is [not allowed (13.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1) to reference the field at run time:

> 3. A reference to a field that is a constant variable (§4.12.4) must be resolved at compile time to the value V denoted by the constant variable's initializer.
>
>    If such a field is non-static, then no reference to the field should be present in the code in a binary file, except in the class containing the field. (It will be a class rather than an interface, since an interface has only static fields.) The class should have code to set the field's value to V during instance creation (§12.5).

The field initializer still runs when you would expect: after `A` constructor has returned and before `B` constructor starts. Observing the uninitialized value is tricky because the compiler inlines the uses of the variable, but you can access the value of the field through reflection:

```
public void action() {
    try {
        System.out.println("B action, finalField="
            + getClass().getDeclaredField("finalField").get(this)
            + ", field=" + field);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A constructor before
B action, finalField=0, field=0
A constructor after
B constructor
B action, finalField=42, field=99
```

Comment: This is it! I can sleep in peace now:)

Answer (score 1):

In java there are two types of flows .

1. Static flow
2. Instance flow

**Static Flow**

Whenever we are executing Parent  Child Class the following sequence of events will
be performed automatically.

- Identification of static Members from Parent to Child
- Execution of Static Variable Assignments and static blocks from parent to child
- Execution of Only Child class main

**Instance Flow**

- Whenever we are executing a Java class static control flow will be executed first.
- Identification of Instance Members from Parent to Child
- Execution of Instance variable assignments and instance block only in parent
  class
- Execution of Parent Class Constructor
- Execution of Instance variable assignments and instance blocks in child class
- Execution of child class constructor

Based on these rules i will try to explain how jvm executes your code .

1. Identifies static member:-> public static void main(String[] args) ;
2. Execute main method
3. Identify instance members in A class first and then B class

> //A class members
>
> protected void action();
>
> //B class members
>
> private final int finalField =42; (since this is final complier will direclty assing it )
>
> private int field =0;(add default values for this member)
>
> public void action();

4. Execution of Instance variable assignments and instance blocks only in parent

// no member to assign

5. Execute Parent Construcor

   First line in  B constructor is super() so the control will go in A class constructor.

   **System.out.println("A constructor before")**

   **action();** //This is little bit tricky ,since the both methods are already
   identified
   by the compiler jvm has two options to choose ,action() in A class or
   action() B ,but
   .since action method is overriden in B class and java for overriden methods
   uses
   Runtime Polimorifizem rule ,it will execute action() method in B classs

   // at this time value of field is 0

   **System.out.println("A constructor after")**
6. Execution of Instance variable assignments and instance blocks only in child
   class

> private int field =99

9. Execute child class constructor

Comment: Sort of, thank you. I need to reed more about it. Have problem with understanding “final” case

Comment: @RomanFrolov for final case i think it is easy . You just need to know that every final variable is evaluated during compile time before jvm stars execution of the program .